# Make dictionary/key pairs based on entire dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that can contain any number of columns. I want to make a dictionary in which the value is the element of column one, and the keys are every other element at the same index for every column.

ex df

```
num  test1   test2  etc...
123    X     test2
999   test1     X
555    X        X
124   test1   test2
```

The idea is to create a dictionary in which every single element (of the same index that is NOT `X`) becomes a key, and the `num` column becomes the value (allowing multi-value dict pairs)

The dict for the above df would be as follows:

```
thisdict = { 'test2':'123,124','test1':'999,124'}
```

Comment: dict can not have dup key

Comment: I'm stuck on handling the `X's` because like you said, cant have the same key twice and at the end of the day I don't need them in there.

Comment: Check your expected output , you have dup key with test2 and test1, both of them shown twice .

Comment: @WeNYoBen updated question, I guess the only way to do it would be keys/multivalue dict pairs.

Comment: maybe work with a `defaultdict(list)`?

Answer (score 0):

I will keep it in `list` rather than string

```
s=df.replace({'X':np.nan}).melt('num').dropna()
d=s.groupby('value')['num'].apply(list).to_dict()
Out[183]: {'test1': [999, 124], 'test2': [123, 124]}
```